# Split string to convert to datetime causes an error

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

I try to convert persian date to standard datetime .The persian date has a format like this :`1392/01/23`.

My function :

```
 public DateTime ConvertPeersianToEnglish(string persianDate)
        {
            string[] formats = { "yyyy/MMMM/dd" };
            DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(persianDate, formats,
                                              CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);

            return d1;
        }
```

So when i call this function and pass my persian date to it i got an error :

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Why ?

Best regards

Comment: it is like this Year/month/day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MM` instead of `MMMM`:

```
string[] formats = { "yyyy/MM/dd" };
```

`MM` is month number `01` to `12`

`MMMM` is full month name `january` to `december` (strings depend on culture).

Check out MSDN: [Custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: So why in standard time we should use MMMM?

Comment: @EA well it all depends on your needs, it is just a different way of representation of your date. Though I've never heard that `we should use MMMM in standard time`, where did you get that from?

Comment: I haven't found anything indicating such thing, so it all depends on expected input format I guess.